# Same code getting Time Out because of "if" statement on LeetCode

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, c++17

The question is taken from LeetCode in which we have to find out whether there are two distinct indices i and j in the array such that the **absolute** difference between **nums[i]** and **nums[j]** is *at most **t*** and the absolute difference between i and j is *at most **k***.
My approach is O(N*N) which should not be acceptable but it is.

Accepted Code:

```
bool containsNearbyAlmostDuplicate(vector<int>& nums, int k, int t) {
    int n = nums.size();
    vector<pair<long long, int>>list;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        list.push_back(make_pair(nums[i], i));
    sort(list.begin(), list.end());
    for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++) {
        for (int j = i+1; j < n && list[j].first-list[i].first <= t; j++)
            if (abs(list[j].second - list[i].second) <= k)
                return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Code which gives Time Out:

```
bool containsNearbyAlmostDuplicate(vector<int>& nums, int k, int t) {
    int n = nums.size();
    vector<pair<long long, int>>list;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        list.push_back(make_pair(nums[i], i));
    sort(list.begin(), list.end());
    for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++) {
        for (int j = i+1; j < n ; j++)
            if(list[j].first-list[i].first <= t)
                if (abs(list[j].second - list[i].second) <= k)
                    return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

I don't get why the first code runs efficiently(as per leetcode) while the second one gives TLE?
The only difference is the use of the conditional "IF" statement inside the loop, which I don't think is very costly.

Question link: https://leetcode.com/problems/contains-duplicate-iii/

Comment: You've not just added an if, you've changed the stop condition for the inner loop.  That can have a major change.

Comment: If `n` can be large, you want to reserve the vector space up front instead of reallocating and copying everything ~logn times while filling it.

Comment: `My approach is O(N*N)` -- If there is a guarantee of when that additional stop condition will occur, and that guarantee gets you something that is < `O(N)` then the first approach is not `O(N*N)`, but something smaller.

Comment: btw, i already answered and I know what TLE stands for, but consider that abbreviations have meaning in a context and as we arent on LeetCode TLE could mean for example [Star Trek: The Lost Era](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TLE). It is a matter of good style not to use abbrevations and simply assume the reader knows what they are supposed to refer to

Comment: Yes, not everyone knows what TLE, WA, AC, and whatever else actually stands for.  I know for whoever uses those sites, they may think that these abbreviations are well-known, but believe me, they're not, except for the people who frequent those sites.

Comment: Three Letter Ecronym, Washington, and Air Conditioning.

Comment: Ok I will update the question. I should have kept that in mind

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie You are right the first approach is indeed less than O(N * N). My original approach was the second one and that is why I mistakenly thought the first code is also O(N * N)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we boil it down to the essential, you are comparing

```
for (int i = 0; i < imax; ++i) {
   if ( some_condition(i) ) {
       // do something
   }
}
```

vs

```
for (int i = 0; i < imax && some_condition(i); ++i) {
    // do something
}
```

The second loop terminates once `some_condition(i)` is `false` while the first always runs all iterations.

Code is very unforgivable when you are sloppy and don't pay attention to details:

> The only difference is the use of the conditional "IF" statement inside the loop

No that is not the only difference!